# How to stop user going to Login/Register & Other non Authenticated pages on MVC3 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, authentication

Once user logins to my site where i use Form Authentication then how can i stop user to going on Login & Register page if he has allready login & register.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two ways "off the top of my head":

**1 -** Custom `Action Filter` that redirects the user from the page if they are logged in.

```
public class RedirectAuthenticatedRequests : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated) {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary(new {
                        controller = "SomeController",
                        action = "SomeAction"
                }
            ));
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

**2 -** Simple check in the `login` action method if the user is logged in.

```
if(Request.IsAuthenticated) return RedirectToAction("SomeOtherView");
```

Comment: I'd create an [AuthorizeAttribute] derived Attribute indeed.

Comment: @Rhapsody can you explain what are the steps to have that Attribute?

Comment: @Xander you mean ActionFilter on Global.aspx?

Comment: @updev No, I mean create an `ActionFilterAttribute` that decorates your `Login` `ActionMethod` ...

Comment: @updev create a different one that just redirects if the request id authenticated ...

Comment: do you have an example how to customize that?

Comment: @updev just updated the answer. nonetheless, there are numerous posts on the web about creating your own `ActionFilter`s

Answer (score 5):

The easy way out is checking in the controller method(login/register) if the user is authenticated, and if it is redirect the user to the page you want:

Something like this for the Login page(same with Register):

```
//
// GET: /Login/Index
public ActionResult Index()
{
     if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){
          //redirect to some other page
          return RedirectToRoute("Home", "Index"); 
     }

     return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the User.Identity.IsAuthenticated property and redirect them appropriately.